# Background-Color is not working with RazorPDF (Mvc view to pdf)

Tags: razorpdf

I am using RazorPDF to convert Mvc view to PDF. everything is working fine... except Background-Color for Div / table tag.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<table backgroundcolor="red">
   <tr></tr>
</table>
```